# Using lodash (or any other node modules) in Jade with grunt-contrib-jade?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-jade

Is it possible to access lodash (or any other node modules) with in a Jade template.

Here is an use case I need to use
Is it possible to access lodash (or any other node modules) with in a Jade template.

Here is an use case I need to use

```
- userNames = _.pluck(users, 'user');
ul
  each name in userNames
  li= name
```

Comment: did you figure this one out?  I finally stumbled across your question here after searching all over...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass Lodash to Jade directly through the `data` field in options.

```js
options: {
  data: function(dest, src) {
    return {
      _: require('lodash')
    };
  }
}
```